# How to use findstr, exclude svn directory in gvim

Tags: svn, vim, cmd, findstr

I want to find out all the files which contain a keyword in a directory and all the subdirectories, and there are some `.svn` directories, I should ingore these directories.

In Linux system, I can do it easily by:

```
  grep -r keyword ./ --exclude-dir ".svn"
```

But when I turn to windows, `findstr` is a substitute for `grep` in windows, I try to do it like this:

```
  findstr /s keyword ./*
```

The result will return with the `.svn` directories, which is not what I want.

I read the [TN Findstr, on microsoft website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)

```
  /v   : Prints only lines that do not contain a match.
```

But when I try it like below, It still doesn't work.

```
 findstr /s keyword /v ".svn" ./*
```

I think there may be some problem with my usage of `findstr`. Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

```
        ***************************** update1 *****************************
```

In fact, I am trying to use `grep` in `GVim`, it will call 'findstr`.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't exclude specific (sub)folders in `findstr`. In PowerShell you could do something like this, though:

```
$root = '.'
$keyword = 'keyword'

Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse -Force | ? {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.FullName -notlike "*\.svn*"
} | Select-String $keyword -AllMatches
```

Or you could make use of the fact that `.svn` subfolders are hidden and do this:

```
$root = '.'
$keyword = "keyword"

Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    Select-String $keyword -AllMatches
```

This won't work, though, if some of the files that you want to search through have the `hidden` attribute set.

Comment: I wonder if they have fixed the `Get-ChildItem -Exclude` switch in PowerShell 3 so you don't have to use the filter. I can't test that where I am right now.

Comment: In fact, I am trying to use grep in `GVim`, it will call 'findstr`.

Comment: @srain Then don't use `grep`?

Comment: `grep` will call outer program `findstr` in `gvim`. Do you mean `set grepprg` to [`Grep for Windows`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)? This would be a good way to use `grep` in `gvim`. But, I intend to do this job by using `findstr` or other dos tool.

Comment: Yes, that might help.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, do you think there is a way to do this job by using `findstr` or other dos tools?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, assuming your files do not return `.svn\` in the content.

```
 findstr /s "keyword" * |findstr /v /i /L ".svn\"
```

Comment: That will not work with VIM's "grepprg" setting, which requires an "open" command line (like `findstr /s`; the keyword and file pattern is appended by VIM). You could/would have to wrap that in a batch file and use that from VIM.

Comment: @Christian.K Vim allows to specify where it puts the arguments via `$*`; see `:help 'grepprg'`.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Oh, I missed that, thanks. But I think using a pipe still doesn't work (well at least I was unable to make it work ;-)

Comment: @Christian.K The pipe needs to be properly escaped, as it's also a Vim command separator.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Indeed. But what is the proper escaping in this case? This 
`:set grepprg=findstr\ /s\ $*\ \ \|\ findstr\ /v\ /i\ /L\ ".svn\\"`, i.e. a simple `"\|"` doesn't seem to work. VIM only considers the left side of the pipe as the external command.

Comment: @Christian.K Yes, escaping (both for Vim and the Windows command prompt) isn't trivial. This seems to work: `:set grepprg=findstr\ /s\ $*\ \ ^\\\|\ findstr\ /v\ /i\ /L\ ".svn\\"`

Comment: @Christian.K, I tested, the `findstr` after pipe still seems not to work. Does it work for you?

Comment: It seems to work (at least syntax wise) when you add escape the quotes around the `.svn` as well: `:set grepprg=findstr\ /s\ $*\ \ ^\\\|\ findstr\ /v\ /i\ /L\ \".svn\\\"`

Comment: @Christian.K , If I want to match `.svn\ `, I should add escape the slash after `svn`, the vim `set grepprg` will be: `:set grepprg=findstr\ /s\ $*\ \ ^\\\|\ findstr\ /v\ /i\ /L\ \".svn\\\\\"`. Thank you for you help again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Christian.K's help, I worked this out:

I set grepprg as below：

```
 :set grepprg=findstr\ /s\ $*\ \ ^\\\|\ findstr\ /v\ /i\ /L\ \".svn\"
```

The options above only match `.svn`.If you want to match `.svn\` in `gvim`, you should:

```
 :set grepprg=findstr\ /s\ $*\ \ ^\\\|\ findstr\ /v\ /i\ /L\ \".svn\\\\\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a bat file find.bat that contains this and type `find . keyword`. You could use a `doskey` to hide having to type the `.` if you wanted.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set curDir=%1
if "%curDir%"=="." set curDir=%cd%
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-h-d %curDir% 2^>nul') do findstr /ilmp %2 %curDir%\%%i
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/ad-h %curDir%') do call %0 %curDir%\%%i %2
ENDLOCAL
```